# Why I get an "invalid request" error when I use Socket to send a http request?

Tags: java, sockets, http

I want to use low-level socket to send a http request then parse the result, but I can not get the correct result, the console tells me that my request is invalid, anyone can help me to find the problem? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
try {
     URL url = new URL(request.getUrl());
     Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost()), 80);
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
     pw.print("GET / HTTP/1.1 \r\n");
     pw.print("Host: " + url.getHost() + "  \r\n");
     pw.print("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 \r\n");
     pw.print("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate \r\n");
     pw.print("Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4 \r\n");
     pw.print("Cache-Control: max-age=0 \r\n");
     pw.print("Connection: keep-alive \r\n");
     pw.print("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 \r\n");
     pw.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Mobile Safari/537.36 \r\n");
     pw.println("\r\n");
     pw.flush();

     InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
     BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

     String line;
     while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line).append('\n');
     }
     System.out.println(buffer.toString());
     } catch (IOException e) {
           callback.onFailed(e.getMessage());
     }
```

And I put an url "http://www.163.com" as member of request, but the console show like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

Is there any question about my request header? but I have searched many resolutions, for example adding "\r\n" , But it can not fixed the question.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing, it should be `\r` `\n`, not `\\r`, `\\n`.

Comment: ...and there should not be a space between the `\r` and the `\n`.

Comment: You did not add `"\r\n"`.  You added the *four characters* `' '`, `'\r'`, `' '`, `'\n'`, which is not a valid newline sequence.  Remove those intervening spaces and your request will be valid.

Answer (score 3):

Your request line is badly formatted - you are missing protocol (and headers and everything else)

[image]

What is the reason for constructing raw requests? Either use library (OkHttpClien, Apache Http Client) or at least `HttpUrlConnection` for simple requests.

You are using `URL` anyway and it has something like `openConnection()` that will do what you want for you.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()

Comment: Thank for your answer! I just want to try the low-level request, and I have tried to complete my request header like this:   `pw.print("GET / HTTP/1.1 \r \n");
                    pw.print("Host: " + url.getHost() + "  \r \n");
                    pw.print("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 \r \n");
                    pw.print("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate \r \n");
                    pw.print("Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4 \r \n"); ...` , but the request is still an invalid request.

Answer (score 1):

```
pw.print("GET / HTTP/1.1 \r\n");
```

Your request line is badly formed. From [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

You have a space before the CRLF. Removing it fixes the problem (and gives a 302 Moved Permanently result).

If you're going to implement HTTP you need a good knowledge of this RFC and its successors. I strongly recommend you avoid all this effort and just use `HttpURLConnection`. It's already done.